# Unable to parse the id from moviedb api

Tags: json, parsing, android-volley

Hi I'm trying to parse out the id's from an array. I have a logging method which shows a toast:

```
StringBuilder data= new StringBuilder();

JSONArray arrayMovies= response.getJSONArray(KEY_MOVIES);

for (int i = 0; i < arrayMovies.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject currentMovie = arrayMovies.getJSONObject(i);

    String id = currentMovie.getString(KEY_ID);

    data.append(id+"\n");
}

L.t(getActivity(), data.toString());
.....
```

But It's not parsing it out. Just getting a list of the movies.

Here is the json file:

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "adult": false,
            "backdrop_path": "/tbhdm8UJAb4ViCTsulYFL3lxMCd.jpg",
            "genre_ids": [
                53,
                28,
                12
            ],
            "id": 76341,
            "original_language": "en",
            "original_title": "Mad Max: Fury Road",
            "overview": "An apocalyptic story set in the furthest reaches of our planet, in a stark desert landscape where humanity is broken, and most everyone is crazed fighting for the necessities of life. Within this world exist two rebels on the run who just might be"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: KEY_MOVIES...results

Comment: you can use currentMovie.getInt(KEY_ID) instead of currentMovie.getString(KEY_ID);

Comment: Hi! Does my answer work for your question?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe because id value has no quote, and therefore, can not be parsed as a String with getString() method

Comment: Assuming you are using org.json.JSONObject, replace "currentMovie.getString(KEY_ID);" by "currentMovie.getInt(KEY_ID);"

Comment: I tried the getInt() method but with no success. The json feed has the id value without quote marks.

Comment: Did you also changed "String id = ..." by "int id= ..." ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is OK, just need check the response and keys again, I have tested with hard-code the response as the String and 2 keys as the following:

```
        String jsonString = "{\n" +
                "    \"page\": 1,\n" +
                "    \"results\": [\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"adult\": false,\n" +
                "            \"backdrop_path\": \"/tbhdm8UJAb4ViCTsulYFL3lxMCd.jpg\",\n" +
                "            \"genre_ids\": [\n" +
                "                53,\n" +
                "                28,\n" +
                "                12\n" +
                "            ],\n" +
                "            \"id\": 76341,\n" +
                "            \"original_language\": \"en\",\n" +
                "            \"original_title\": \"Mad Max: Fury Road\",\n" +
                "            \"overview\": \"An apocalyptic story set in the furthest reaches of our planet, in a stark desert landscape where humanity is broken, and most everyone is crazed fighting for the necessities of life. Within this world exist two rebels on the run who just might be\"\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    ]\n" +
                "}";
        StringBuilder data= new StringBuilder();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray arrayMovies= jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayMovies.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentMovie = arrayMovies.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = currentMovie.getString("id");
                data.append(id+"\n");
            }
            Log.i("BNK", data.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And here is the screenshot (please pay attention to logcat):

[image]